# How to ask the user to create a new object in java as an attribute while creating another object from another class?

Tags: java, class, object

So I basically have 2 classes as a part of a little bank system program, client and account, the client have 3 attributes, name age and account where account is an object of the account class that I created, when I launch the program I basically create an account then create a client while using the created account as an attribute for that client

How can I only create an object of the client class and during that creation I ask the user to create an account object at the same time to use it as an attribute for the first object?

I tried to ask the user to create an object of a class during the operation of creating another object from another class to use the first object as an attribute in the second object.

This is my code:

```
package bankpackage;

public class Client {
    private String nom;
    private String emploi;
    private Compte compte;
    public Client(String nom, String emploi, Compte compte) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.emploi = emploi;
        this.compte = compte;
    }
}
```

And:

```
package bankpackage;

public class Compte {
    private long numero;
    private float solde;
    public Compte(long numero, float solde) {
        super();
        this.numero = numero;
        this.solde = 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your last sentence is confusing.  An end user cannot create an instance of a class.  The user enters information, such as text and numbers, and the *program* uses that information to create instances of classes.  That aside, your question would be a lot easier to understand if you would edit your class and show your account and client types as code, instead of just describing them.  It doesn’t even have to be real code;  just something like `public class Client` accompanied by the signature of the constructor, like `public Client(String name, int age, Account account)`, would help.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, this is my code
package bankpackage;

public class Client {
 private String nom;
 private String emploi;
 private Compte compte;
 
 public Client(String nom, String emploi, Compte compte) {
  super();
  this.nom = nom;
  this.emploi = emploi;
  this.compte = compte;

package bankpackage;

public class Compte {
 private long numero;
 private float solde;
 
 public Compte(long numero, float solde) {
  super();
  this.numero = numero;
  this.solde = 0;
 }

Comment: Any important information, and especially any code, should be in the question itself, and not in comments, where it can be missed, and where code cannot be formatted or easily read. Please [edit] the question, add the code, and also make the question more clear and easier to understand.

Comment: I didn't get to insert it in the post, tried C+K, space, annotations, still didn't work

Comment: You're missing any IO code, code where you interact with the user.

Comment: @sherdean Click the *Edit* link to change the body of your Question.

Answer (score 0):

> during that creation I ask the user to create an account object

No, never complicate the constructor of an object. Do not interact with the user while constructing an object.

**Constructors should be short and sweet, and safe**, with little that can go wrong.

A key notion here is [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Your user-interface code should be separate from your business logic code.  In the UI code, gather needed inputs from user. After that, create your business objects, instantiating the `Client` and `Account` classes.